# What is the most practical way mount this sort of module having no pins?

Tags: soldering

This module has no pins and the pitch between two pins is about 1.5mm. Eventually I want to be able to push it in a breadboard, so pitch is important and mechanical stability too.

[image: This module]

What is the best option to mount this thing? Can I safely solder the contacts? Do I have to be aware of anything special?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There would be nothing wrong with fixing the module to a bare board or piece of plastic using glue, then soldering individual wires to the each of the contacts.

Hot melt glue is good for this.

Bring the individual wires to a veroboard (aka breadboard) for further connections.

You could make your own PCB, it's really easy.

I'm an EE with 20+ years experience, but I still have a DIY light box for this purpose.

There are plenty of Youtube videos and websites telling you how you can create a basic PCB in you kitchen or garage.   There are free, or low cost tools available to generate the artwork.

If you don't want to make your own, there are companies like PCBTrain or PCBPool that reduce the cost of simple PCB production.

Comment: I have also mounted modules like this on a little prototype board [like this one](http://www.radioshack.com/product/index.jsp?productId=2104052).  I solder 30-gauge wire-wrap wire to the module's contacts first, then mount it using glue and run the wires to the nearest holes.  You probably won't need to use anywhere near all the contacts, as most Bluetooth modules can be controlled using a UART (TX, RX), plus a reset line, maybe a mode and/or status lines, and power/ground.  You can add a 2x10 (or whatever) 0.1" header and run a ribbon cable to wherever you are controlling it with.

Comment: "You probably won't need to use anywhere near all the contacts, ..." That is a brilliant hint, I should have thought of that myself.

Answer (score 2):

This probably isn't what you want to hear, but the cleanest and most reliable way to do it would be to buy/make a breakout PCB.  This would give you all pins in two neat rows, perfect for breadboarding.  Depending on what it is (Bluetooth module, by chance?), you may also be able to buy a version already on a breakout for a couple bucks more.  You could also make your own if you are at all familiar with PCB design.  If not, this could be a great starting point :)

As for special considerations, they likely have all the bypassing, etc, that they require, so you would just need to give it a clean power source (i.e. stable voltage with a decent size electrolytic cap somewhere on the rail).  It also wouldn't hurt to have a generous amount of ground plane (NOT under or in front of the antenna) that is well connected to the device's ground, which could improve your RF.

Comment: Bluetooth Master / Slave module. The version that I know of on a break out board is a slave only module.